# TomTom Map api black dots on the map

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging, maps, tomtom

I am using the TomTom map API. But when I'm using the map there are so many black dots and boxes(as seen on the image below). When I zoom in the dots and boxes disappear, but then the new dots and boxes disappear. PS: I have not done anything special, I just added the map to my Android studio project as TomTom wanted.

[Example Image of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/646QX.png)

Comment: have you checked on multiple devices? It looks like a rendering issue. I didn't see it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a TomTom issue whilst running in the android emulator, this does not appear running on android devices. Same issue is shown in TomTom documentation.